# .gitlab-ci.yaml throws "Cleaning up file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1" at the end after successfully run the job

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, sam

When I am trying to commit changes to gitlab for continuous integrations i am facing this error even though all my steps pass successfully,  Gitlab CI shows this

- *Cleaning up file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1*

I am running 1 stages "deploy" at the moment here is my script for deploy:

```
image: python:3.8

stages:
  - deploy

default:
 before_script:
    - wget https://golang.org/dl/go1.16.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    - rm -rf /usr/local/go && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.16.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
    - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
    - source ~/.bashrc
    - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade

deploy-development:
 only:
  - feature/backend/ci/cd
 stage: deploy
 script:
    - sam build -p
    - yes | sam deploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command probably creates an issue in the docker shell:

```
yes | sam deploy
```

Try this command:

```
sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html:

```
--confirm-changeset | --no-confirm-changeset    Prompt to confirm whether the AWS SAM CLI deploys the computed changeset.
--fail-on-empty-changeset | --no-fail-on-empty-changeset    Specify whether to return a non-zero exit code if there are no changes to be made to the stack. The default behavior is to return a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Amazingly it works without giving any error!!
I've used this command:
```sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```